# ansible match variable pattern to json output

Tags: json, ansible

I am using the Ansible vmware_vm_info module to generate json like this:

```
    {
  "virtual_machines": [
    {
      "guest_name": "serverx",
      "datacenter": "datacenter",
      "guest_fullname": "Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 (64-bit)",
      "esxi_hostname": "host1",
      "tags": [
        
      ],
      "cluster": "cluster1",
      "vm_network": {
        
      },
      "mac_address": [
        
      ],
      "attributes": {
        
      },
      "folder": "",
      "power_state": "poweredOff",
      "ip_address": "",
      "uuid": "33234323oijdlk"
    },
    {
      "guest_name": "server2_01112022",
      "datacenter": "datacenter",
      "guest_fullname": "Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)",
      "esxi_hostname": "host1",
      "tags": [
        
      ],
      "cluster": "cluster1",
      "vm_network": {
        
      },
      "mac_address": [
        
      ],
      "attributes": {
        
      },
      "folder": "",
      "power_state": "poweredOff",
      "ip_address": "",
      "uuid": "287292lkqjjjjd"
    },
```

I have a variable that reads a csv and sets the vmname like this:

```
vmname
server1
server2
```

I need set a new fact that will look for the vmname string existing in the vminfo json output.  In the example above, server2 would match server2_01112022.

I have tried the following but I don't get a match:

```
  - set_fact:
      renamedvm: "{{ item.guest_name }}"
    with_items:
      - "{{ vminfo.virtual_machines }}"
    when:
      - item.guest_name |regex_search('^result_item.vmname.$')
```

Comment: your variable vmname is a list ? or a string multiline?

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](/help/mcve) and be more specific about the exact result you want to get. The above is absolutely not clear.

Comment: I want to set a fact (renamedvm) that matches server2 (in my csv) to server2_01112022 (in vminfo output).  Later in my playbook I will do things like power on the renamedvm, etc.

Comment: => `{{ virtual_machines | map(attribute='guest_name') | select('search', 'server2') }}`

Comment: Zeitounator, your solution works but it has square brackets around the name like this: "renamedvm": ["server2_01112022"].  Is there a way to get rid of the square bracket?  Its causing later tasks to fail.

Comment: I figured it out - I can do renamedvm[0] and it works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For example, given the list

```yaml
  vmname: [server1, server2]
```

the task

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        renamedvm: "{{ renamedvm|d({})|combine({item: _value}) }}"
      loop: "{{ vmname|unique|sort }}"
      vars:
        _selection: "{{ virtual_machines|selectattr('guest_name', 'search', item) }}"
        _value: "{{ _selection|map(attribute='guest_fullname')|list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  renamedvm:
    server1: []
    server2:
    - Microsoft Windows Server 2012 (64-bit)
```